# Scalable way to use the Snackbar in Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar

This is not a post to have a solution but to discuss the project structure on Compose.

I'm currently learning Compose and I have difficulties to understand how to use the Snackbar in a project. Most examples I've seen are basic examples to call the Snackbar once with the `SnackbarHostState` from the Scaffold.

However, when working on an app that has an MVVM structure, I don't understand how the snackbar can be called from anywhere, except transmitting the state from a composable to another.

However, I would like the snackbar use to not be that restrictive. Is there any scalable way to use the Snackbar yet with Compose?

Answer (score 2):

Setup;

```
ExampleTheme {
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val LocalSnackbarHostState = compositionLocalOf<SnackbarHostState>{
        error("No Snackbar Host State")
    }
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        values = arrayOf(
            LocalSnackbarHostState provides snackbarHostState
        )
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackbarHostState) },
        ) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Call wherever you want;

```
val snackbarHostState = LocalSnackbarHostState.current
snackbarHostState.showSnackbar()
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good use-case for [CompositionLocals](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal) - a way to pass dependencies down the tree implicitly. First, make sure each screen-level composable provides a `SnackbarHostState` or some kind of snackbar manager, which wraps the `SnackbarHostState` (if you'd like to add some logic on top of the standard behaviour). After that at any place in your app use the provided `CompositionLocal` to show a snackbar.